# How can I scrape a table from a website in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm tying to extract the bottom table ('Daily Observations') from https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/dc/washington/KDCA/date/2011-1-1. I got to the full xpath for the table component but it shows `{xml_nodeset (0)}` as the output. What am I doing wrong here? I used the following code:

```
library(rvest)
single <- read_html('https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/dc/washington/KDCA/date/2011-1-1')  
single %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = '/html/body/app-root/app-history/one-column-layout/wu-header/sidenav/mat-sidenav-container/mat-sidenav-content/div/section/div[2]/div/div[5]/div/div/lib-city-history-observation/div/div[2]/table')
```

It seems that the table component is empty.

Comment: I would recommend using the rnoaa package and extract the data directly from the Governments NOAA website.  The other option is to use the web browser's developer's tools and locate the JSON file containing the requested data.

Comment: @Dave2e the rnoaa package doesn't allow access to more recent (after 2010) hourly data which is important for my analysis. I can't locate a JSON file assigned to the data on the wunderground website, possibly there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a dynamic page, with the table generated by Javascript.
`rvest` alone will not suffice. Nonetheless, you could get the source content from the JSON API.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(lubridate)
library(jsonlite)

# Read static html. It won't create the table, but it holds the API key
# we need to retrieve the source JSON.

htm_obj <- 
  read_html('https://www.wunderground.com/history/daily/us/dc/washington/KDCA/date/2011-1-1')

# Retrieve the API key. This key is stored in a node with javascript content.
str_apikey <- 
  html_node(htm_obj, xpath = '//script[@id="app-root-state"]') %>%
  html_text() %>% gsub("^.*SUN_API_KEY&q;:&q;|&q;.*$", "", . )

# Create a URI pointong to the API', with the API key as the first key-value pair of the query
url_apijson <- paste0(
  "https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KDCA:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=",
  str_apikey,
  "&units=e&startDate=20110101&endDate=20110101")
# Capture the JSON
json_obj <- fromJSON(txt = url_apijson)

# Wrangle the JSON's contents into the table you need
tbl_daily <- 
  json_obj$observations %>% as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(valid_time_gmt = as_datetime(valid_time_gmt) %>% 
                          with_tz("America/New_York")) %>% # The timezone this airport (KDCA) is located at.
  select(valid_time_gmt, temp, dewPt, rh, wdir_cardinal, gust, pressure, precip_hrly) # The equvalent variables of your html table
```

### Results: A nice table

```
# A tibble: 34 x 8
   valid_time_gmt       temp dewPt    rh wdir_cardinal gust  pressure precip_hrly
   <dttm>              <int> <int> <int> <chr>         <lgl>    <dbl>       <dbl>
 1 2010-12-31 23:52:00    38    NA    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 2 2011-01-01 00:52:00    35    31    85 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 3 2011-01-01 01:52:00    36    31    82 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 4 2011-01-01 02:52:00    37    31    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 5 2011-01-01 03:52:00    36    30    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 6 2011-01-01 04:52:00    37    30    76 NNE           NA        30.1          NA
 7 2011-01-01 05:52:00    36    30    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 8 2011-01-01 06:52:00    34    30    85 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
 9 2011-01-01 07:52:00    37    31    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
10 2011-01-01 08:52:00    44    38    79 CALM          NA        30.1          NA
# ... with 24 more rows
```

Comment: This is amazing! You've saved me a couple of days of copying and pasting. Thank you!